# csquotes: always enclose blockquote in " "

Tags: punctuation, quoting, csquotes

I'm trying to force `csquotes` to always set a `\blockquote` in display mode but still enclose the quote in quotation marks, German ones in particular.

How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern,blindtext}

\usepackage[babel=true,strict=true,german=quotes,threshold=1]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blockquote{\blindtext}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This example produces a quote as an indented paragraph, but without quotation marks.

Comment: Something like `\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\enquote{#1#2#3}#4}` should work, see section 8.7 _Hooks for Quotations and Citations_ of the [`csquotes` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/csquotes) for details on `\mkblockquote`

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try. If it works I would happily accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`csquotes` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/csquotes) suggests to redefine `\mkblockquote`, see section 8.7 *Hooks for Quotations and Citations*. One possibility would be

```
\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\enquote{#1#2#3}#4}
```

which gives the same effect as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135682/5049).

The four arguments of `\mkblockquote` refer to

```
\mkblockquote{<text>}{<punct>}{<tpunct>}{<cite>}
```

which are explained in the manual as follows

> - `#1` The text argument of the command.
> - `#2` The optional `<punct>` argument of the command. If there is no `<punct>` argument, this parameter is empty.
> - `#3` Trailing `<tpunct>` punctuation immediately after the command. If there is no such punctuation or if the `autopunct` feature is
>     disabled, this parameter is empty.
> - `#4` The optional `<cite>` argument of the command, wrapped in `\mkcitation`. If there is no `<cite>` argument, this parameter is
>     empty. With integrated quotation commands, this parameter is the
>     citation code, wrapped in `\mkccitation`.

In the example below I use

```
\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{,,}#1#2#3``#4}
```

where `\llap{,,}` places the opening quotation mark left of the text in the quote margin. (The space at the end before the closing quotation mark is an artefact of `\blindtext` and not related to `\mkblockquote`.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern,blindtext}

\usepackage[babel=true,strict=true,german=quotes,threshold=1]{csquotes}

\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{,,}#1#2#3``#4}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blockquote{\blindtext}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice result! thx!

Comment: Instead of `\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{,,}#1#2#3``#4}` we could use `\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{\textooquote}#1#2#3\textcoquote#4}` for localization-awareness. Unfortunately the tracking with `\openautoquote`/`\closeautoquote` does not work.

Comment: I cooked up `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{\openautoquote\csq@eqgroup}\csq@bqgroup\advance\csq@qlevel\@ne#1#2#3\closeautoquote#4}
\makeatother` just now, which seems to do all the tracking as advertised.

Comment: @moewe Ah, probably being hidden in the `\llap` box is a problem for `\openautoquote` and the tracking mechanism

Comment: Yes, I suppose it has to do with grouping.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `\enquote{...}` inside the `\blockquote` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern,blindtext}

\usepackage[babel=true,strict=true,german=quotes,threshold=1]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blockquote{\enquote{\blindtext}}   %<=======================

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @jon That seems to be a problem with `\blindtext`, it puts a space at the end. If one uses a text without a space at the end, everything works as expected.

Comment: it would be nicer if the opening quotes were set just outside the quote margin.

Answer (score 0):

I added `threshold=1` and `thresholdtype=words` to the `\usepackage`-Command to enforce blockquotes even at short quotations.

The `threshold` option refers to words or lines (default). In combination with `thresholdtype=words` the threshold for block-quotes can be set to one word.

For me the following command worked well until now:

```
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=english, threshold=1, thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
```

The [package documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/csquotes/0) at page 4 shows the following options:

> **threshold=〈integer〉**
>
> default:3
>
> This option defines the number of lines or words the block quotation
> facilities useas a threshold when determining whether a quotation
> should be typeset in inline orin display mode.  It corresponds to
> the\SetBlockThresholdcommand.  See §§ 3.5and 8.6 for further details.
>
> **thresholdtype=lines**
>
> wordsdefault:lines
>
> This option selects the block threshold type. Withthresholdtype=lines,
> the blockquotation facilities will determine the number of lines
> required to typeset the quo-tation; withthresholdtype=words, they
> count the number of words in the quota-tion.3The default threshold
> setup is 3 lines. If you prefer something like 50
> words,setthreshold=50andthresholdtype=words. See § 3.5 for further
> detail

Answer (score 0):

Taken (and adapted) from [MoeWe](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=119539&sid=15a71e3b883c13549d1d0b693c74fd23#p119539).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    autostyle,
    strict=true,
    english=american,
    threshold=2
    ]{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{%
    \leavevmode\llap{\openautoquote\csq@eqgroup}%
    \csq@bqgroup
    \advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
    \csq@resetstyle
    \csq@init}
    
\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{%
    \leavevmode\llap{\openautoquote\csq@eqgroup}%
    \csq@bqgroup
    \advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
    \csq@resetstyle
    \csq@init
    #1#2#3\closeautoquote#4}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{\closeautoquote\normalfont#1#2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{displayquote}[Blind Text]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}

\blockquote{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered text]